# Insert the current date (format yyyy/mm/dd) into a list box -

Tags: delphi, date

I need to insert the date at the end of the following line

```
lstReport.Items.Add('***** END OF REPORT *****');
```

Answer (score 6):

[`FormatDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) would be appropriate:

```
lstReport.Items.Add('***** END OF REPORT ' +
     FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', Date) + ' *****') ;
```